# Meteor and filepicker-plus package

Tags: meteor, filepicker.io

I am having a little bit of trouble outputting a image after a filepicker selection with the [file picker plus package](https://atmospherejs.com/natestrauser/filepicker-plus) from meteor. How to I grab the uploaded image url or file path, so I can pass it into a form input and put it in a collection. Putting in into the collection isnt the part I am worried about its getting the path that I am having trouble with cheers.

All contained in postSubmit template.

I have a form with

```
<input type="filepicker" name="myName" />
```

and a img output in the same template

```
  <img src="{{filepickerIdToUrl myName}}">
```

and a router file containg

```
     Router.onBeforeAction(function(){
    loadFilePicker('magickey');
   //can leave out key if its in settings
   this.next();

},{only:['postSubmit']});
```

Here is the full postSubmit template

```
<template name="postSubmit">
  <form>
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input name="title" id="title" type="text" value="" placeholder="Name your post"/>
      <button id="uploadImage" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</button>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
    <img id="imagePreview" class="img-responsive" src="{{filepickerIdToImageUrl imageId placehold_it='500x350' h=200 w=300}}"/>
                    <button id="removeImage" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</button>
```

This is also my postSubmit events

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
      image: $(e.target).find('[name=image]').val()

    };

    Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
      // display the error to the user and abort
      if (error)
        return alert(error.reason);

      Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: that's my package!  can you post more code to be clearer about what you are doing?

Comment: @nate-strauser I have added the full postSubmit code. I am wanting the image to show up on the page after it is selected from the file picker. Eventually I will pass the url into a hidden field and submit the post but for now, i Just want to see the image selected on the form template page/

Comment: Do I need to do the meteor.settings part?

Comment: Here is what its doing, it just picks the file then closes. http://g.recordit.co/Br0didnprt.gif

Comment: could it be because it thinks that the image select is a form submit event.

Comment: that gif doesnt load for me.  do you actually get the filepicker dialog or just a standard web file dialog?  the filepickeridtourl helper wont work until you actually get the id.  showing a preview in the form is tricky, have to use session to store the intermediate values, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/BFUGZ2jBq0Y   i'll see if i can work up an example that is close to what you are trying to do in the next day or so

Comment: I get the the file picker dialog. I will look at this forum to get the id. I have sorta of used session before so I think I understand what your saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nate and the google groups link above, I got it working.

Here is my solved code,  Right now it only shows the preview on the form and you can remove it by clearing the session value, but it will be easy enough to grab that session value and put it into the form on submit.

Thanks again Nate.

```
Template.postSubmit.created = function(){
    Session.setDefault("imageId", null);
    Session.setDefault("imageKey", null);
};



Template.postSubmit.events({



  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
      title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val(),
      image: $(e.target).find('[name=image]').val()

    };

    Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
      // display the error to the user and abort
      if (error)
        return alert(error.reason);

      Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});
    });
  },
  'click #uploadImage':function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        filepicker.pickAndStore(
            {
                mimetypes: ['image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png'],
                multiple: false
            },{
                access:"public"
            },
            function(InkBlobs){
                                // the upload is now complete to filepicker - but the form hasnt persisted the values to our collection yet
                Session.set("imageId", _.last(_.first(InkBlobs).url.split("/")));
                Session.set("imageKey", _.first(InkBlobs).key);
                                //  once the session changes are made, the form will now have the new values, including a preview of the image uploaded
            },
            function(FPError){
                log.error(FPError.toString());
            }
        );
    },

    'click #removeImage':function(event, template){
        event.preventDefault();
        Session.set("imageId", "remove");
        Session.set("imageKey", "remove");
    }
});

Template.postSubmit.helpers({
    'hideRemove':function(){
        return Session.equals("imageId", null) || Session.equals("imageId", "remove");
    },
    'imageId':function(){
        if(Session.equals("imageId", "remove"))
            return "";
        else
            return Session.get("imageId") || "";
    },
    'imageKey':function(){
        if(Session.equals("imageKey", "remove"))
            return "";
        else
            return Session.get("imageKey") || "";
    }
});
```